# How to acess Symfony 2 formview.valid variable in twig template

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have tried to use the variable `form.valid` in a twig template rendering a form, but I get an error starting with

> Method "valid" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not
>   exist

Here is the code generating this error

```
{% if form.valid == false %}
  <p class="error"> There is an error in the form. please Correct. </p>
{% endif %}
```

So my question is: is this variable already available or we have to explicitly set it in the controller, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method isValid() is from Form class and not from FormView, which is the one that you are passing to the template when on your controller you return $form->createView().

[According to the Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference), you can check the validity of a form with:

```
{% if form.vars.valid == false %}
   <p class="error"> There is an error in the form. please Correct. </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does this need that I set a variable `errors` in my controller?

Comment: Yes That one worked, thanks. I think I did not understand the doc.

Comment: Is it possible to validate a single input field in the form instead of the entire form?